# What is the best way to load node connections into TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a text file containing node connections of a network

Here is the current format of the text file where each node id is connected to another node id on a single line in the file

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
3 4
```

I want to load this network into a NumPy array to do KMean Clustering

Code to do KMean Clustering takes a NumPy array as input: https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/k-means-clustering-with-tensorflow/

What is the best way to

a) To store the network connection information (I have control over this)

b) To read the file into TensorFlow as a NumPy array

Update:

Taking this code as an example: https://gist.github.com/dave-andersen/265e68a5e879b5540ebc

On line 11 where it loads the points randomly

```
points = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([N,2]))
```

How would I load these points from a static file?

Is there a particular format the file should be in or is text/csv the best option? (I have control over the format of the file being read in)

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a network of interactions between people.

I want to use Machine Learning/Deep Learning to analyze the relationships between these nodes using TensorFlow

Once I have the node connections loaded into TensorFlow I can start working on various types of analysis but first I want to make sure I load the data into tensor flow correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way that works for me but still not 100% sure it is the best way to achieve what I want.

Using this code as a basis: https://gist.github.com/dave-andersen/265e68a5e879b5540ebc

On line 11 where it loads the points randomly I use the numpy.loadtxt method that mrry suggested and pass it into a TensorFlow.constant_initializer then use the TensorFlow.get_variable to convert it into the points

```
init = tf.constant_initializer(np.loadtxt('node_links.txt',skiprows=0))
points = tf.get_variable('points', shape = [902946, 2], initializer = init)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`numpy.loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function is the easiest way to load text data into a NumPy array:

```
points_array = numpy.loadtxt(filename, dtype=numpy.int32)
```